# Dealing with namespaces while parsing XML in Go

Tags: xml, go, xml-namespaces

I am trying to parse a piece if XML in Go:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type XML struct {
    Foo string `xml:"foo"`
}

func main() {
    rawXML := []byte(`
<xml>
  <foo>A</foo>
  <ns:foo>B</ns:foo>
</xml>`)

    x := new(XML)
    xml.Unmarshal(rawXML, x)
    fmt.Printf("foo: %s\n", x.Foo)
}
```

This outputs:

```
foo: B
```

While I expected it to produce:

```
foo: A
```

How do I get content of the first `foo` tag (i.e. one without namespace)?

Comment: I think this may be a bug in the Go itself. https://codereview.appspot.com/6868044/ and https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=3526 . View the goplay example in the second link, I believe it's the reverse issue you face but if it fails in reverse it likely fails in your direction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think the xml decoder can specify an element should have no namespace with struct tags. But I do know that it can retrieve the information about the namespaces for you and you could then post process the data after to get the same result:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type Foo struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
    Data string `xml:",chardata"`
}

type XML struct {
    Foo []Foo `xml:"foo"`
}

func main() {
    rawXML := []byte(`
<xml>
  <foo>A</foo>
  <ns:foo>B</ns:foo>
</xml>`)

    x := new(XML)
    xml.Unmarshal(rawXML, x)
    //fmt.Printf("foo: %#v\n", x)
    for _, el := range x.Foo {
       if el.XMLName.Space == "" {
          fmt.Printf("non namespaced foo %q", el.Data)
      }
    }
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/aDEFPmHPc0

Answer (score 4):

You have two values in series in your xml document.  You only have room for one value in your struct.  The xml parser is parsing the first one and then overwriting it with the second one.

Change Foo to a slice in the struct and then you'll get both values.

http://play.golang.org/p/BRgsuMQ7rK

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type XML struct {
    Foo []string `xml:"foo"`
}

func main() {
    rawXML := []byte(`
<xml>
  <foo>A</foo>
  <ns:foo>B</ns:foo>
</xml>`)

    x := new(XML)
    xml.Unmarshal(rawXML, x)
    fmt.Printf("foo: %s\n", x.Foo[0])
    fmt.Printf("both: %v\n", x.Foo)
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get just one without namespace? (example is contrived, in real thing there is a lot of tags with various namespaces in unspecified order, and I need just one that does not have any)

Answer (score 1):

The `xml:"foo"` selector syntax takes an optional namespace `xml:"ns foo"`, but the problem is that it doesn't support a way to select for no namespace.

One fix is to use `xml.Decoder.DefaultSpace` to simply assign a namespace to non-namespaced tags that you can now select using `xml:"<ns> <tag>"` syntax:

https://play.golang.org/p/1UggvqLFT9x

```golang
import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "strings"
    "fmt"
)

type Doc struct {
    Foo string `xml:"_ foo"` // <-- <foo> will now be <_:foo>
    NsFoo string `xml:"ns foo"`
}

var input = `<xml>
  <foo>A</foo>
  <ns:foo>B</ns:foo>
</xml>`

func main() {
    decoder := xml.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(input))
    decoder.DefaultSpace = "_"

    doc := &Doc{}
    decoder.Decode(doc)

    fmt.Printf("<foo>: %#v\n", doc.Foo)
    fmt.Printf("<ns:foo>: %#v\n", doc.NsFoo)

}
```

Prints:

```
<foo>: A
<ns:foo>: B
```