# Iterate over elements in xml with namespace

Tags: xml, go, xmpp

I want to operate with XMPP users with `github.com/mattn/go-xmpp` Golang package. I change a little official [example](https://github.com/mattn/go-xmpp/blob/master/_example/example.go#L67) and got something like this:

```
switch v := chat.(type) {
case xmpp.IQ:
    if len(v.Query) != 0 {
        fmt.Printf("Query: %s", v.Query)
    }
default:
    fmt.Printf("detect default type: %T\n", v)
}
```

`v.Query` is a XML document with namespace like

```
<query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster">
<item jid="JID1" name="Name" subscription="none" ask="subscribe">
    <group></group>
</item>
<item jid="JID2" name="Another name" subscription="both">
    <group>Group</group>
</item>
<item jid="JID3" name="Eman" subscription="both">
    <group>AnotherGroup</group>
</item>
</query>
```

How can I parse this document and iterate over `jid` elements?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like, for example, [the `xml` package](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/)?

Comment: Of course I tried, but all examples is `xml` package documentation doesn't illustrate namespaces.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14152832/229154) may be helpful for your case.

Answer (score 0):

There are two mechanisms for parsing XML documents in the standard library, a streaming mechanism and a struct based mechanism.

---

**Streaming API**

Using the streaming mechanism will be a tad more verbose, but also very efficient for large documents (such as a large roster). The basic idea would be to create a decoder, iterate over the tokens and extract the data you need. In this case, you just need the JID attribute which will only be on the start elements, so you will also need to iterate over the attributes of each start element to find one named "jid". The following is a minimal example of doing this, for a real project you'd likely also want to validate that each start element is an "item":

```
func main() {
    d := xml.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(v.Query))
    var jids []string
    for {
        tok, err := d.Token()
        if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
            panic(err)
        }
        if tok == nil {
            break
        }
        start, ok := tok.(xml.StartElement)
        if !ok {
            // We'll skip anything that's not a start element in this example.
            continue
        }

        jid := getAttr("jid", start.Attr)
        if jid != "" {
            jids = append(jids, jid)
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(jids)
}

func getAttr(name string, attr []xml.Attr) string {
    for _, a := range attr {
        if a.Name.Local == name {
            return a.Value
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

You can run this example on the playground here: https://play.golang.org/p/s6flTADDsnT

---

**Struct based API**

The struct based API is a little easier, but also may be less efficient with a large roster. Instead of streaming the XML payload token by token, we'll create a struct that represents the payload, unmarshal the data into it, and then iterate over it and pull out the JIDs. A struct representing the roster response would look like this:

```
type rosterResponse struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"jabber:iq:roster query"`
    Items   []struct {
        JID string `xml:"jid,attr"`
    } `xml:"item"`
}
```

An example of unmarshaling into it can be found here:

https://play.golang.org/p/g2qLUkdZ7qt

For a better understanding of what is going on in these two examples, I highly recommend reading the package level documentation for [`encoding/xml`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/), it covers all this and a lot more useful information!